Matrix of orthogonal Projection onto a Hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$
We consider the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the usual scalar product. Let $H = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \, | \, a_1x_1 + \ldots + a_nx_n = 0 \}$, where $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ are given real numbers, not all equal to zero. Find the matrix in the standard basis for the orthogonal projection onto $H$.
I am new to this and this problem really confuses me. I tried to find a basis for this subspace but it was fruitless, then I noticed that the vector $(a_1, ..., a_n)$ is basis for $H^\perp$. Technically one could use this to construct a projection matrix onto $H^\perp$, but I don't see how that would be useful.
Any help please.

Hint: If you have a projection onto $P$ onto $H$ and projection $P_\perp$ onto $H^\perp$, what is $P + P_\perp$?

@NicholasTodoroff Of course, the identity! I tried to calculate the projection matrix earlier for $H^\perp$, I found $$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1^2 & a_1a_2 & a_1a_3 & \cdots & a_1a_n \
a_1a_2 & a_2^2 & a_2a_3 & \cdots & a_2a_n \
a_1a_3 & a_2a_3 & a_3^2 & \cdots & a_3a_n \
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \
a_1a_n & a_2a_n & a_3a_n & \cdots & a_n^2 \
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The matrix I'm looking for is the identity minus the one I found correct?

Exactly! You should write everything up as an answer and accept it.

Yep, that is a good proposal @NicholasTodoroff .
For the answer, you, mmmmh mmmmmh, should notice that the given projection matrix onto $H^\perp$ is correct only under the additional assumption that $(a_1, ..., a_n)$ is normalised to $1$.
